# The sum of consecutive digits

Tags: diophantine-equations, natural-numbers

a) Find the natural numbers ${\overline{ab}}$ such that

${\overline{ab}}= a+(a+1)+...+b$.

b) Exist natural numbers ${\overline{abc}}$ such that

${\overline{abc}} = a+(a+1)+...+{\overline{bc}}?$;

Generalization.

In case a), using arithmetic progression sum, obtain the equation ${\overline{ab}}= \frac{(a+b)(-a+b+1)}{2}$ solutions having:
15, 27.

Comment: Can you check your last equation? There should be some minus signs around? $a=2, b=7$ doesn't satisfy it currently.

Answer (score 0):

$2.10^na+2x=2\overline{ax}=x(x+1)-a(a-1)$ where $x$ could be $\overline{b},\overline{bc}...$

$ x^2-x-a^2-(2.10^n-1)a=0$ has solutions $\displaystyle x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4a^2+4(2.10^n-1)a}}{2}$. There are no integer solutions for $n=2,3,4,6,7$. For $n=5$, $a=19048, x=47620$ is the only solution.

Comment: Your solution should check equality $19048+19049+19050+...+47620=1904847620$.